# GA4 doesn't collect my event parameter but GTM collects

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

I'm currently new to GA4 + GTM

What I wanna do is, whenever I click button , I will run function `login` and if `login` is successful, I want to collect user `A` has logged in. (Just a test case!!)

So what I did is,

setting all snippets on `head`, Run below function which pushes data to dataLayer.

```
function collectGTMEvent(eventName, ...param) {
    if (!window) {
      console.warn("WARNING: current execution environment is not browser");
      return;
    }
    if (!window.dataLayer) {
      console.warn("WARNING: GA script is not loaded");
      return;
    }
    window.dataLayer.push({
      event: eventName,
      ...param,
    });
    }
```

Whenever I run function, event parameters aren't collected in GA4 debug view, but collected in GTM debug tool.

and whenever I set a default value to event parameter value, on GA4 debug view, only default value is shown (which means my parameters which are passed to dataLayer.push function aren't passed to GA4...)

I've strongly confident that there wasn't any error while configuring GTM. + GA4 datastream

[GTM debug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VefhC.png)